# getting Uncaught Error: Cannot include a '?' character in a manually specified.... on Link Container

Tags: reactjs

```
<Nav>
        <Nav.Item>
          <strong>Categories</strong>
        </Nav.Item>
        {
          categories.map((category) => 
          (
            <Nav.Item key={category}>
              {/* <Link
                to={`/search?category=${category}`}
                onClick={() => setSidebarOpen(false)}
              >
                {category}
              </Link> */}
              <LinkContainer
                to={`/search?category=${category}`}
                onClick={() => setSidebarOpen(false)}
              >
                <Nav.Link>{category}</Nav.Link>
              </LinkContainer>
            </Nav.Item>
          ))
        }
      </Nav>
```

Hi i'm getting this error and the thing is i used this kind of code before and i didnt get any error at all, and I don't get any error when using just the Link(the one that is commented out) but when I use this container i get this error
[Uncaught Error: Cannot include a '?' character in a manually specified `to.pathname` field [{"pathname":"/search?category=Cameras"}].  Please separate it out to the `to.search` field. Alternatively you may provide the full path as a string in  and the router will parse it for you.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrL6N.png)

Answer (score 2):

react-router `6.4.2`, `6.4.1`, `6.4.0` have issue on `?` character !

- `6.4.2` on `<Link>` + `<NavLink>` tags.
- `6.4.1` && `6.4.0` on `<Route>`.

Use version `6.3.0` to get rid of this annoying issue for now.

Comment: This answer implies this is a bug that will get fixed in future versions, which is not correct.  The new behavior (disallowing paths with query params) is "working as intended", and will not be fixed.  User's encountering this problem need to update their code to change the problematic paths.  See https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/9613#issuecomment-1320812151 for details.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution for react-router-dom@6.7.0 and react-router-bootstrap@0.26.2

Typescript:

```js
interface Props {
  children?: React.ReactNode | ((props: { isActive: boolean; isPending: boolean }) => React.ReactNode);
  to: To;
}

export default function FixedLinkContainer({ to, children }: Props) {
  let path: Path;
  if (typeof to == 'string') {
    const url = new URL(to as string, window.location.origin);
    path = {
      hash: url.hash,
      pathname: url.pathname,
      search: url.search,
    };
  } else {
    path = to as Path;
  }
  return <LinkContainer to={path}>{children}</LinkContainer>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Found the solution for `v6.4.x`

Example:

```
import {Link} from "react-router-dom"

const Comp = () => {
  return (
    <div>

      <Link
        to={{
          pathname: "/search",
          hash: "#hash",
          search: "?category=abcd", 
        }}
      >
        Link Text
      </Link>

    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I only removed this ?

```
   it was like that
   to={`/search?category=${category}`}

   I changed to 
   to={`/searchcategory=${category}`}
```

It works now